# What is the comparative form of холодный?

Tags: перевод, грамматика

What is the comparative form of холодный?

холоднéе//похолоднéе//холоднéй//похолоднéй

Comment: Can you provide some context? As it stands, it's not clear what you're asking and this question is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 9):

**-ей** forms of comparatives are either colloquial or poetic, and in both cases they're used in free variation with **-ее**. A more formal style of speech requires **-ее** only.

Now as regards **по-**, there's a limited number of contexts where you'd use it. Firstly, when you talk about "a colder X" as opposed to "X is colder"; e.g. *В странах похолоднее, вроде России или Канады, плотность населения меньше.* "Colder countries such as Russia or Canada have lower population density." Note that you could also use **поменьше** in that sentence, which brings us to the second use of **по-**, which is a little harder to pinpoint. Say, in that last sentence, "a little harder" is a clear case for **потруднее** — which already kind of implies the "a little" part; but that doesn't quite mean that **по-** denotes a small difference; rather, that difference isn't great (so it could be small or just "regular"), but it's definitely one that you'd notice.

Another use of **по-** is to denote a desired increase in a certain quality. *Готовят там отлично, а вот пиво могло бы быть похолоднее.* "The cooking's great there, but the beer could be colder". *Побольше бы таких сюрпризов.* "I wish we had more surprises like that." (I know it's an adverb here rather than an adjective, but it works the same way.)

Comment: +1 If you use _там_, then the beer could **have been** colder. But that's just a remark, I don't insist. ;)

Comment: @YellowSky Not if it was warm on several occasions and will likely be warm the next time. I think.